# jprofiler. run GC using triggers

Tags: triggers, garbage-collection, jprofiler

The main task is to make 5 steps in jprofiler using triggers on remote server.

1. Start recording memory
2. Wait until end of method usage
3. Run GC
4. Stop memory recording
5. Save snapshot

How Can I run GC using triggers?
In actions jprofiler I got "run script". I tried to put there System.gc() but in UI it doesnt actully saved the script.

Also I tried to export session and manually rewrite part for "RunGC" adding
`System.gc()` in run script part of config.xml

```
        <runScript>
          <script id="1" compiledClassName="" lastModified="0">
            <code>System.gc()</code>
          </script>
        </runScript>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Run GC" action for triggers in JProfiler.

[image]

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/5ab00c8224821e11d654013c857064d9.png I got version 8.1.4. There is no option RUN GC

can I use run script and how?

Comment: Please try the current version of JProfiler, we don't support 8.x anymore.

Comment: My company got keys only for 8.x version.

Comment: You can use the evaluation version from the web site.